# Can I make a whole site in node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

I want to make a new website. Is it good programming approach if I am make whole site in node.js on server side?

I also know PHP if that is better.

Comment: *This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: "is PHP better" is *highly* subjective. If you'd spent more that 5 seconds ramming out the question, and had instead focussed on the stability of [node], and questioned the specific parts you're not sure node supports (DB interaction? View rendering?) you *might* have had a decent question.

Comment: NodeJS gives all features, required to build a site/app. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Actually, node is *designed* to be able to handle a large  number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: @DaveRandom: node allows you to spawn additional threads through [`WebWorkers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) or through the likes of the [`cluster` module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html)

Comment: @Matt Neat, never actually seen that before, all my node has been for relatively small apps where a single thread will never be 100% utilised. Although I still maintain it's better to use a well established server you you don't have to re-invent the wheel with things like URL rewriting and DDOS protection

Comment: @DaveRandom: I agree that it's still new and un-established, but at the rate modules and libraries are being added and the ubiquity JavaScript enjoys I don't think it'll take as long to become established as nginx and apache took :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build your whole site with `node.js`. The benefit of doing this is that you are using the same language for both the server-size page generation and client-side interactions.

For example, here's a simple one to find photos from flickr near a user: https://github.com/ericf/photosnear.me

The above uses [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/) for the client side interaction.

Since you mentioned that you know PHP, it is entirely up to you as to whether you want to build the application with `node.js`. Do you want to learn how to use `node.js`? Then build it with `node.js`. Does the project schedule have a tight deadline and you won't have time to learn `node.js`? Then use PHP.

These might be a good one to get started

- http://www.nodebeginner.org/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js

I also recommend [Javascript: A Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000480). The 6th edition contains an entire section on server-side javascript and node.js.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial to start building complete site in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Node is still a young platform. While you can indeed make a whole site or web app using Node, it takes some experience with learning the platform, and is not particularly friendly to beginners. I'd stick with PHP to put sites together quickly, and experiment with Node until you learn it well enough to know when you should use it.